# Dirac Hamiltonian in Peskin & Schroeder

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, hamiltonian, dirac-equation

I am currently going through the Peskin & Schroeder and have hit a snag with what seems should be an easy derivation.

We see that the Dirac Lagrangian Density is given by
$$\mathcal{L} = \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi,\tag{3.83}$$
where $$\bar{\psi}=\psi^\dagger\gamma^0.\tag{3.32}$$

From this, it seems to me that the Hamiltonian Density should be given by

$\mathcal{H}=\pi\partial_0\psi-\mathcal{L}=i\psi^\dagger\partial_0\psi-\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi = i\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^0\partial_0\psi-\bar{\psi}i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi + \bar{\psi}m\psi$
$ = i\bar{\psi}\gamma^0\partial_0\psi-i\bar{\psi}\gamma^0\partial_0\psi + i\bar{\psi}\boldsymbol{\gamma}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi + \bar{\psi}m\psi = i\bar{\psi}\boldsymbol{\gamma}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi + \bar{\psi}m\psi$

$= \bar{\psi}(i\boldsymbol{\gamma}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla} + m)\psi= \psi^\dagger(i\gamma^0\boldsymbol{\gamma}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla} + m\gamma^0)\psi$

But the book gives, in equation (3.84), the form $$\mathcal{H} = \bar{\psi}(-i\gamma^0\boldsymbol{\gamma}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}+m\gamma^0)\psi,\tag{3.84}$$ with a different sign for the 3-momentum term.

Have I made an error in my calculation? I would be inclined to think it a typo, but he uses the same sign in the subsequent equation (3.85).

Answer (score 2):

I think that maybe you are interpreting  ${\boldsymbol \gamma}\cdot \nabla$ as $\gamma_a \partial _a$ while  P&S probably mean  ${\boldsymbol \gamma}\cdot \nabla\stackrel{?}{=} \gamma^a \partial_a $. The sign then comes from $\gamma^a=-\gamma_a$ in (+,-,-,-) metric.

Comment: At the beginning of the book "Notations and Conventions", they give the formula $$ p\cdot x=g_{\mu\nu}p^\mu x^\nu=p^0x^0-\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{x} $$ as an example, which seems to suggest they mean the usual euclidean product.

Comment: In that case I am inclined to agree with your version and not theirs. In my own notes I have $H= \psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^i( -i\hbar \partial_i + m)\psi$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are including a spurious minus sign in your summation. The index contraction over $\mu$ should be

$$\gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} = \gamma^0 \partial_0 + \gamma^1 \partial_1 + \gamma^2 \partial_2 + \gamma^3 \partial_3 = \gamma^0 \partial_0 + \vec{\gamma} \cdot\nabla$$

The reason the minus sign occurs in a sum like $p \cdot x$ is because the metric is necessary for the dot product: $p \cdot x = g_{\mu \nu} p^{\mu} x^{\nu}$. But if you're contracting a covariant and a contravariant index like in $\gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}$, then the Einstein summation is just shorthand for leaving out the $\sum_{\mu}$ symbol. For example, the four-vector $p_{\mu} = (p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3) =(p^0, -p^1, -p^2, -p^3)$, so $p_{\mu} x^{\mu} = p_0 x^0 + p_1 x^1 + p_2 x^2 + p_3 x^3$ as expected.